# SSIS -Oracle Source to Oracle destination

Tags: ssis

I am tying to load data from Oracle to Oracle using SSIS.There are like 70 million records .I am using Oledb Source/Destination.

Is there any efficient way of doing the same load using other's like ADO.Net Source/Destination and i also want to load in batches.

Please let me know which would be the good way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: What's "good" mean to you? Good for speed, good to the database, good to design, good for maintenance? Batching might be a good idea, how do you propose to identify batches? In the event of a restart, how will identify the remaining batches. Is this an ongoing process or a one-time extract? If ongoing, how do you identify and resolve changes to already transferred data?

Comment: like performance wise.Its going to be truncate and insert and i will be doing it weekly.Batch insert is what i am planning to do.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be SSIS? Anyway, there are two ways (at least I have used both successfully) to do this.

- use SQL*Loader. It's an Oracle tool for bulk load.
- use Oracle Data Access Component (documentation and DLL available on the Oracle web site) in the Script Task.